# Azure App Service: SSL/TLS on Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, azure-web-app-service, windows-embedded-compact

We created Web API that hosted with Azure App Service and communication from our instrument with Windows Embedded Compact 7.
The compact framework was working fine all the while and until recently, we found that it stops working with the exception of “Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS”
We suspect it could be due to the [Breaking change for SNI-SSL hostnames](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/02/breaking-change-for-sni-ssl-hostnames-on-azure-app-service/). How can we resolve this in Compact Framework?

Thanks